# How can I exactly replicate the APA bibliography style?

Tags: bibliographies, apa-style

I am trying to write a paper that requires the references to be done exactly in the APA style.

At the moment I am using natbib, and I get the following results:

Beall, J. C. and Restall, G. (2006). *Logical Pluralism*. Clarendon Press, Oxford.

Becker, K. (2012). Methods and How to Individuate Them. In Becker, K. and Black, T., editors, *The Sensitivity Principle in Epistemology*, pages 81--97. Cambridge University Press, Cambridge.

Dutilh-Novaes, C. (2015). A Dialogical, Multi-Agent Account of the Normativity of Logic. *Dialectica*, 69(4):587--609.

But what I need is:

Beall, J. C. & Restall, G. (2006). *Logical Pluralism*. Oxford: Clarendon Press.

Becker, K. (2012). Methods and How to Individuate Them. In K. Becker & T. Black (Eds.), *The Sensitivity Principle in Epistemology*, pp. 81--97. Cambridge: Cambridge University Press.

Dutilh-Novaes, C. (2015). A Dialogical, Multi-Agent Account of the Normativity of Logic. *Dialectica*, 69, 587--609.

Switching to apacite does not seem to help. I've seen a few people suggest biblatex-apa, but I'm not quite sure how this will work with natbib (I also use Mendeley to produce the library.bib file, if that's important). I am quite new to LaTeX, so an answer spelling what I need to do containing as little jargon as possible would be immensely appreciated!

Comment: Both `apacite` and `biblatex-apa` implement pretty exact versions of the APA style. Here are examples using each package: [How can I implement a comprehensive apa-style citation and bibliography](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/352812)

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "Switching to apacite does not seem to help". Did you change the argument of `\bibliographystyle` AND change `\usepackge{natbib}` to `\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}` AND rerun LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more?

Comment: Also helpful: [What is the relationship between natbib, apacite package, and apa document class?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/263793)